# Execution is overlapped nodes created by docker selenium grid and distribution with testNG data provider how avoid this?

Tags: docker, testng, docker-compose, selenium-grid, testng-dataprovider

I am using Docker selenium Grid.
Created multiple nodes and Success with launching my scripts in single node but when i use multiple nodes my execution statements has been passes to recent activated node.
Ex: I have login verification and this is managed with a dataprovider, and need to check run the test method for 6 user credentials.
In current situation up to the browser launch is running as expected i mean 6 nodes launched the browser but the first launched node is taking all the user credentials, In user name it is expected to type 'User001' but it is typing 'User001User002User003...'.
Please provide a solution for this...
Find the attached screen how i launching hub and nodes.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You would need to show us the test code. Without looking at how you are instantiating your webdriver and how you are running your tests using TestNG data provider, its hard to say.

Comment: I have added a BaseSetup class and extended in test class...
And the browser instance initiation done in BaseSetup BeforeMethod and PageObjects intiated by passing the instance created in BaseSetup from test class BeforeMethod.

Comment: Please share the test code. Without seeing the test code it would be hard to comment.